# MOSFET selection for motor control inverter circuit

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor

I am working on developting software and hardware for driving a 1.35 kW BLDC motor with Hall sensors. It's going to be powered by a 48 V battery pack

- Continuous current: 35 A (DC)
- Peak current: 45A (DC)
- Peak phase current limit: 100 A (RMS)

How can I calculate the number of MOSFETs and their rating needed for this inverter design?

Comment: This question is quite wide and cannot easily be answered as you haven't settled on a specific design for your motor driver circuit. Break this up to smaller steps and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: I am new to motor controller development. Can you please guide as per your experience what could be a satisfactory solution.?

Comment: What have tried so far? Avoid parallel MOSFETs if possible. Buy bigger ones instead.

Comment: Do a search for mosfets that meet your criteria 48V @ 100A.  Usually you’d have some tolerance, so maybe 100V 150A. Do your basic calcs like loss and temp rise. Rinse and repeat until you have a satisfactory solution. You might have size, cost and availability constraints. Most manufacturers have search facilities to help you. Also search for application notes for something close to what you’re wanting. There maybe helpful hints and design help in them.